# Extend type of parameter in derived class

Tags: typescript

I wish to be able to override `foo` method in overloaded class, but I wish to make sure that `event` parameter must inlcude `"aaa" | "bbb"`.

Below code shows what I try to achieve, but gives an error that types is not assignable.

```
class ble {
    foo<T>(event: T | "aaa" | "bbb") {
    }
}

class ble2 extends ble {
    foo(event: "ccc" | "aaa" | "bbb") {
        super.foo(event);
    }
}
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it should be the class's parameter, not method's

```
class ble<T> {
    foo(event: T | "aaa" | "bbb") {
    }
}

class ble2 extends ble<"ccc"> {
    foo(event: "ccc" | "aaa" | "bbb") {
        super.foo(event);
    }
}
```